# Add row dynamically in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, rows, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I want to dynamically add a row in a table whenever this function is called from a different class. Right now it crashes the program. I looked through many topics but couldn't find anything.

```
public void newRow(String time, String cloc, String loc, String contact) {
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
    TextView t3 = new TextView(this);
    TextView t4 = new TextView(this);
    t1.setText(time);
    t1.setText(cloc);
    t1.setText(loc);
    t1.setText(contact);
    tr.addView(t1);
    tr.addView(t2);
    tr.addView(t3);
    tr.addView(t4);
    tl.addView(tr, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new instance of TableLayout on each call

Comment: then how do I add the TableRow in the TableLayout?

Comment: pass table layout instance to method too.

Comment: post your logcat please

Answer (score 0):

- Create a global instance of TableLayout so that it will be accessible
  in newRow() method. Remember that you would want to creat just one
  TableLayout and repeatedly add new rows to it.
- You are calling setText() method repeatedly on t1 instance. I don't
  think you intend to do that.
- Post the crash logs so that I could help you further.